# Update table in SQL Server from two comma separated string parameter

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Update a table from two comma separated parameter as input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14681422/update-a-table-from-two-comma-separated-parameter-as-input)

I have a Gridview in front end where Grid have two columns : ID and Order like this:

```
 ID        Order

 1           2
 2           4
 3           1
 4           3
```

Order column is editable. Now if I want to update the order and make save I want to store it into database. I have stored ID and Order as a comma separated string like sID(1,2,3,4) and sOrder(2,4,1,3) and sent to SQL Server as input parameters. Through Stored procedure how can update into the table.

Comment: any code that you've tried ? if yes, please post it.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a *Function* that your Stored Proc can call to split the input parameters.

Refer to: [How do I split a string so I can access item x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/split-string-in-sql)

Answer (score 0):

Sources from various sites to come up with this:

```
DECLARE @sID nvarchar(max) = '1,2,3,4'
DECLARE @sOrder nvarchar(max) = '2,4,1,3'

DECLARE @Split char(1) = ','
DECLARE @xSID xml
DECLARE @xOrder xml

SELECT @xSID = CONVERT(xml,'<root><s>' + REPLACE(@sID, @Split,'</s><s>') + '</s></root>')
SELECT @xOrder = CONVERT(xml,'<root><s>' + REPLACE(@sOrder, @Split,'</s><s>') + '</s></root>')

SELECT [Value] = T.c.value('.','varchar(20)') FROM @xSID.nodes('/root/s') T(c) 
SELECT [Value] = T.c.value('.','varchar(20)') FROM @xOrder.nodes('/root/s') T(c)
```

replace the `@sID` and `@sOrder` as parameters for you SP.

Must add that this site pretty much answered the question: [Social MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/4126a010-6885-4eb0-b79c-c798c90edb85)